# Identity-Aware Proxy Error in Google Cloud Platform 4003

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I stopped the instance in GCM and rerun it again but I got this error:

[image: error message]

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Cloud FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq):

> **Error Code 4003**
> This might mean the instance isn't listening on the port you're trying to connect to or the firewall is closed. Either of those issues could also cause the start-up connectivity test to the VM instance to fail.

As suggested, you should try connecting without Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.
Check if your [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) allow SSH connection, you should look for `default-allow-ssh`
If the firewall and IAP do not resolve your issue, you can follow this guide: [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh)
I had the same problem couple of times, but they resolved themselves after couple of minutes.